# Drop specific column in multiple sheet of workbook using pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, indexing

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJxFq.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TJzj.png)

I have a real-world problem at work. I need to delete the column D, F and J all at once.

I tried printing first all the sheet names and run a for loop but I am getting a KeyError: 'labels [3] not contained in axis'

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

fileName = 'project_dropColumnICS.xlsx'
df = pd.ExcelFile(fileName)

arrayOf_SheetNames = df.sheet_names

#just to print the sheetNames
for sheetName in arrayOf_SheetNames:
    print(sheetName)

for sheetName in arrayOf_SheetNames:
    masterdf = pd.read_excel(fileName, sheet_name=sheetName)
    masterdf = masterdf.drop(3, axis = 1)
    masterdf = masterdf.drop(5, axis = 1)
    masterdf = masterdf.drop(9, axis = 1)
```

Also, how to implement dropping 3 columns all at once in each sheet? I'm afraid what I'm doing is dropping just one and then, when it is time to drop the other two, it might delete wrong columns because of incorrect indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use integer indexers with [`pd.DataFrame.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) to extract the *labels* required for [`pd.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
masterdf = masterdf.drop(masterdf.columns[[3, 5, 9]], axis=1)
```

The integers 3, 5, 9 relate to letters D, F, J respectively in Excel.